# Visual Basic Console Application Copy Percentage?

Tags: vb.net, copy, console-application, percentage

I am making a Console Application that will copy larger files (up to 2 GB) (with My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory) and I would like make a percentage indicator. I just want it to show the current percentage in numbers (ex. 23%). I'm new to Visual Basic and I have no idea how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to tag this with the appropriate language.  It doesn't look like you're talking about VBA here.  In general, you'd want to enumerate the files in the directory, then either change the displayed percentage each time you copy a file (if you want to display percent of files copied) or sum the sizes of all the files, then display the percentage of bytes copied as you copy each file.  Might want to display, e.g. "Copying file: xxxx.ext (nnnn bytes)" so the user has an idea how long the copy might take.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply print line like this:

```
"Copy process: 30% done    \r"
```

to the console (note few extra spaces in the end - you will need them to erase old junk). Also note that `\r` will return cursor the the beginning of line, so next print will occupy the same line.

Answer (score 2):

Here a code sample to show percentage indicator in a console application:

```
For i = 1 To 100
  Console.Write(String.Format("Copy progress: {0}%" & vbCr, i))
  Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
Next
```

VB.NET does not react to `\r`, you need to use `vbCr` const instead.

Also notice that you don't need extra spaces in the end, because percentage values will always increase - cleanup is not necessary.